# Recover data from a QR code with the last 2 lines missing

Tags: qr-code

Bitcoin.
I have 250BTC on a qr code that i discover only now has the last 2 lines missing.

If my math is correct, 2 lines (width is around 25 pixels, so 2 lines = 50 boxes that can be only black or white)

```
2^50 = 10^15 combinations.
```

The qr code produces a 30-character hash, i have the first 13 characters of the hash.

Is there any way you suggest me to try to recover the money?

Comment: QR codes have some level of redundancy built in. Your indication of a 25x25 data region indicates a V2 code. I would try to 'fill in' into your QR code for the non-colored and non-gray portions of [this image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:QR_Code_Structure_Example_2.svg) and leave the rest of the missing portion empty, i.e white.

Comment: this is the bottom of the qr code, the missing part: http://i.imgur.com/OZWVROC.png your suggestion dosen't apply, correct?

Comment: Right - thats what I was suggesting. If this does not read, then you have several million combinations to try. To continue working with what you have, I can recommend matcing the missing portion with the white tone of the data portion, and removing the white 'borders' between the pixels that you have pasted. Try different QR readers. I cant think of anything else that could be done for this.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the last two lines are part of the finder pattern at the bottom-left, which has no information (you can easily draw it back in). It's surrounded by a white gutter of 1 module, and the next column over (moving right) is part of the format information section. This is error-correctable itself, but, is also replicated at the top right. You won't need this bit.

The rest is indeed information in a v2 code. You're missing only 16*2 = 32 bits, or 4 codewords. The minimal error correction for a QR code, level L, has 10 EC codewords. It can correct 10 errors. Just leave the area white, and all the codewords will be errors, but that's easy to correct with room to spare by any decoder.

Just draw back in the finder pattern.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/dA8IOM7.png ; this is a qr code made from the same application, i ereased 8 units of information from the bottom right and i'm unable to read it.

Comment: it's a version 4 qr code with a CRC level set to H, that should mean that you can lose up to 30% of the words. Yet, i can't solve this...

Comment: My gmail is srowen, just send it over. I'll have a look.